# File name or class name not found during Automation operation

Tags: .net, com, .net-2.0

I am developing a web service which is consuming a COM component, that in turn calls GetObject method.
I could see the service working fine if the target framework is set to Version 4.0, but it gives following error while target framework is 2.0

```
File name or class name not found during Automation operation
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a 32 vs 64-bit issue? When you retarget, do you keep the same bitness?

Comment: Yes, I keep the same bitness... The target platform is set to 32-bit only, which I didn't change after downgrading the .NET Framework

Comment: Something in the environment is probably changing (security/identity, registry, rights, etc.) with the framework version change.